# Как внутри echo поставить php код?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[post_id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"]'); ?>
```

Как правильно запихать phpкод в php? 
Пробовал так

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[post_id="\<?php the_ID(); ?>\"]'); ?>
```

Хочу вывести галерею внутри записи вордпресс по айди

Answer (score 5):

Правильно будет `get_the_ID`. `the_ID` сам по себе уже эхо

Попробуй

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[post_id='".get_the_ID()."']"); ?>
```

или

```
<?php
$id= get_the_ID();
echo do_shortcode("[post_id='$id']");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

А так нельзя?
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[post_id="'.the_ID().'"]'); ?>`

Comment: нет, `the_ID()` выводит запись, а возвращает другая функция: [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)

Comment: @BOPOH вот вот! спасибо! как раз get нужен был)